# Java - Assign Value to Fixed Byte Array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, byte

I'm am attempting to assign an integer value to an abnormal fixed size byte array (3). I saw about ByteBuffers allocate feature, however putInt attempts to put in 4 bytes, which then breaks due to overflow

For Example:

```
byte[] messageLength = ByteBuffer.allocate(3).putInt(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("300")).array();
```

Results in the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:527)
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:372)
```

Obviously, 300 can fit into 3 bytes since in binary it is 0001 0010 1100.

What can I do to put a perfectly legal sized integer value into a non 4 byte array?

Comment: `new byte[] { (byte)(i >> 16), (byte)(i >> 8), (byte)i }`

Comment: ^---- do that, learn about bit shifting >>

Comment: My question is why do you want to do this?  Do you know about `DataOutputStream`?

Answer (score 0):

You need 4 bytes to allocate an Integer inside a byte buffer.
You can read from the byte buffer manually if you need a special unpacking rule.

Here's an example:

```
public static byte[] convertInts(int[] source) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * source.length);
    for (int data : source) {
        buffer.putInt(data);
    }
    buffer.flip();

    byte[] destination = new byte[3 * source.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        buffer.get();
        destination[i * 3] = buffer.get();
        destination[i * 3 + 1] = buffer.get();
        destination[i * 3 + 2] = buffer.get();
    }

    return destination;
}
```

Example usage:

```
int[] source = {
    Integer.parseUnsignedInt("30"),
    Integer.parseUnsignedInt("300"),
    Integer.parseUnsignedInt("3000"),
    Integer.parseUnsignedInt("300000"),
};
byte[] data = convertInts(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to convert the `Integer` value into a `byte[]` that contains only the necessary bits. The following code works with integers that fit in 1, 2, 3 and 4 bytes:

```
private static byte[] compressInteger(int value) {
    if (value >= Byte.MIN_VALUE && value <= Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
        return new byte[] { (byte) value };
    } else if (value >= Short.MIN_VALUE && value <= Short.MAX_VALUE) {
        return new byte[] { (byte) (value >>> 8), (byte) (value) };
    } else if ((byte)(value >>> 24) == 0) {
        return new byte[] { (byte) (value >>> 16), (byte) (value >>> 8), (byte) (value) };
    } else {
        return new byte[] { (byte) (value >>> 24), (byte) (value >>> 16), (byte) (value >>> 8), (byte) (value) };
    }
}
```

If you want to convert the `byte[]` back to an integer value, you can do:

```
private static int decompressInteger(byte[] bytes) {
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int bit = 0; bit <= 7; bit++) {
            boolean isSet = ((bytes[i] >>> bit) & 1) == 1;
            if (isSet) {
                int shift = 8 * (bytes.length - 1 - i) + bit;
                int mask = 1 << shift;
                value |= mask;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```